# Clearing a context when drawing on Famo.us CanvasSurface

Tags: javascript, canvas, famo.us

I want to implement a custom `render()` method on a Famo.us `CanvasSurface` instance (or subclass thereof). I succeeded in drawing in the surface's context, but could not get the context to be cleared between animation frames.

This is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/Y9gUU/1/):

```
Famous.loaded(function () {
    var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
    var Modifier = Famous.Core.Modifier;
    var RenderNode = Famous.Core.RenderNode;
    var CanvasSurface = Famous.Surfaces.CanvasSurface;
    var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;

    var appContext = Engine.createContext();

    var canvas = new CanvasSurface({
        size: [500, 300],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    });

    var i = 0;

    // The line should move downwards, beginning at the top. Instead, clearRect() seems to have no effect at all.
    canvas.render = function render() {

        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        ctx.moveTo(10, i);
        ctx.lineTo(60, i);
        ctx.stroke();

        i++;

        return this.id;
    };

    appContext.add(canvas);

    Engine.pipe(Application);
});
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, clearRect() is working, but would work better if you were doing a fillRect() for the draw.
Here is the modified code(http://jsfiddle.net/uxE8k/1/)

```
canvas.render = function render() {

        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        ctx.fillRect(10, i, 50, 1);
        //ctx.moveTo(10, i);
        //ctx.lineTo(60, i);
        //ctx.stroke();

        if (i++ > ctx.canvas.height) i = 0;

        return this.id;
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! Your version did work too, but I solved my problem by adding `ctx.beginPath()` before drawing the line (see answer above).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ctx.beginPath()` before drawing the line solved the problem.

This is the updated code (http://jsfiddle.net/Y9gUU/6/):

```
Famous.loaded(function () {
    var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
    var Modifier = Famous.Core.Modifier;
    var RenderNode = Famous.Core.RenderNode;
    var CanvasSurface = Famous.Surfaces.CanvasSurface;
    var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;

    var appContext = Engine.createContext();

    var canvas = new CanvasSurface({
        size: [500, 300],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    });

    var i = 0;

    // The line should move downwards, beginning at the top. Instead, clearRect() seems to have no effect at all.
    canvas.render = function render() {

        var ctx = this.getContext('2d');

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(10, i);
        ctx.lineTo(60, i);
        ctx.stroke();

        i++;

        return this.id;
    };

    appContext.add(canvas);

    Engine.pipe(Application);
});
```